# i got error, polyfills-es2015.js:4001 Unhandled Promise rejection: A reference does not exist for the specified audio id. ; Zone: <root> ; Task

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, audio

audio()  {

```
this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('sound', '../../assets/ar-XA-Standard-A.mp3')
.then((success)=> { 
console.log('sucess',success);
},(err) =>{
  console.log('err',err)

})

this.nativeAudio.play('sound', (success) =>{
console.log('sucess',success);
```

})

}

this is my code for playing an audio file in a button click just but I got the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change path to 'assets/ar-XA-Standard-A.mp3'

```
this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('sound', 'assets/ar-XA-Standard-A.mp3')
.then((success)=> { 
console.log('sucess',success);
},(err) =>{
  console.log('err',err)

})

this.nativeAudio.play('sound', (success) =>{
console.log('sucess',success);
```